# How to customise the "invalid date" in moment

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Im trying to customise the error message of moment when a date is invalid, so I don't get "Invalid Date" each time.

For exemple one time I would like the result to be blank if the date is not correct, an other time I want it to be "This date is not correct"

Is there any way to do so ?

I searched everywhere and didn't find anything, so far the only way is to change it that way

```
moment.updateLocale("es", {
  invalidDate: "Fecha invalida"
});
```

But it's just to change the message everywhere. I want to be able to custom it everywhere.

So the only solution I found so far is to use the function

```
isValid();
```

And so create a function like

```
CustomMomentErrorMsg(moment(...), 'my error msg')
```

and the function can look like this

```
function CustomMomentErrorMsg(MyDate, errorMessage) {
  if (MyDate.IsValid()) {
    return MyDate
  }
  else {
    return errorMessage      
  }
}
```

or something like

```
function CustomMomentErrorMsg(MyDate, errorMessage) {
  if (MyDate == "Invalid Date") {
    return errorMessage      }
  else {
    return MyDate
  }
}
```

Isnt there a way just like

```
moment(MyDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY").error("This is a custom error message")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [moment's source code](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js), you'll see that the error message for an invalid date is part of the locale configuration, and the `format()` function internally calls the `formatMoment()` function, which, in turn, checks for validity and returns the global locale configuration for the error message text:

```
function formatMoment(m, format) {
    if (!m.isValid()) {
        return m.localeData().invalidDate();
    }
    // the rest of the code doesn't interest us in your case
}
```

( those functions can be understood as getters for internal properties `._locale` and `._invalidDate` which can, but absolutely should not be accessed by the end user as it's considered bad practice - this is why there is this public API available ).

Default (parent) locale configuration is stored in the `baseConfig` variable:

```
var baseConfig = {
      calendar: defaultCalendar,
      longDateFormat: defaultLongDateFormat,
      invalidDate: defaultInvalidDate,
      ...
      ...
      ...
      meridiemParse: defaultLocaleMeridiemParse,
};
```

and the default value is set a few lines above like this:

```
var defaultInvalidDate = 'Invalid date';
```

As you can see, the error text is not a property of the `moment`, it's a property of the `locale` and so can't be different for different moment objects. Unless you're willing to change the locale settings every time you generate a new date, the solution that you provided seems legit and usable!

P.S. I put some related `console.log()` in this code snippet

```js
// creating an invalid moment
var m = moment.invalid();
// don't use properties that begin with underscore!
console.log(m._isValid);
console.log(m.isValid());
// formatting returns the same result as toString()
// and the general message in the locale data object
console.log(m.format());
console.log(m.toString());
console.log(m.localeData()["_invalidDate"]);
console.log(m.localeData());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Comment: So there is no way to custom it simply until using function :/
Thanks !